# How can I tell KafkaAvroSerializer that the connection to the Schema Registry must be through a proxy?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I try to point out my request by means of a curl call:

**Schema Registry call without tunneling any proxy:**
`curl -X GET -i https://schema-registry-url:8081/subjects/someTopic-value/versions/`

**Schema Registry call with tunneling proxy**
`curl -X GET -i https://schema-registry-url:8081/subjects/someTopic-value/versions/ --proxy http-proxy.net:3128`

My Kafka connection is implemented via my Spring-Boot application. As serializer I have the KafkaAvroSerializer, which implies the schema registry. Here is an Overview of my producerConfig:

```
`
 public Map<String, Object> producerConfig(){
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokerAddress);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroSerializer.class.getName());
    props.put(KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistry);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
    return props;
  }
`
```

However, this configuration does not tunnel the HTTP proxy. So it is like the first curl call.

**Question**: 
How can I specify in my producer configurations that the schema-registry client should pass a proxy?

--> is there a method that can be overwritten?

--> is there another parameter that can set this?

Thank you for your help and ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try to set that on your Spring Boot app's JVM settings, for example if you're doing this in IntelliJ Idea you need to add the JVM args in your Run Configuration.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible, due to the fact that the application also contains other HTTP calls, which are not all allowed to go through the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

The confluentinc team has recently made an expansion to the Library.

Check here the changes for additional proxy configs, that will be used to connect to the schema registry instances:

https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/pull/1144